# Javascript actions not working on category page

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, jquery

I deleted : -

jquery-1.7.2.min.js

and

jquery-noconflict.js

From the mangeto installation folder js/ias/

As I saw there was an error / conflict being read when using Inspect Element on the category page. Maybe due to using AdBlockPlus. Very stupid of me anyway.

After I put the files back all javascript actions have ceased to operate on the category page however they still work elsewhere on the website.

I have tried flushing the cache and other things but functionality on the category page has not returned.

What can I do?

Comment: In Admin -> System -> Cache Management ... did you "Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache"?

Comment: First of all why you have deleted these files ?

Second, have you added any JavaScript/jQuery code to the <head></head> tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that you add back in the exact same file, in the same location, with the same file name.  A good way to do this is often downloading a clean copy of Magento, be sure its the same version you are currently using.  Be sure to undo any .phtml or XML changes you may have made that deal with loading javascript.

2.Go in to the Magento admin (System -> Cache Management) and flush **all** caches.

- Flush Magento Cache
- Flush Cache Storage
- Select All, Action = Refresh, Submit
- Flush Catalog Image Cache
- Flush Javascript/CSS Cache
- To test this in your browser use Chrome - Incongnito mode or Firefox - Private Window to make sure that you aren't getting a locally cached version of the page.

Assuming there were no other changes made that should fix it for you.